# Replace existng column in MSR

Tags: microsoft-r

Why does the following MSR code not replace the original column "Var1"?

```
rxDataStep(inData = input_xdf, outFile = input_xdf, overwrite = TRUE,
       transforms = list(Var1 = as.numeric(Var1)),
       transformVars = c("Var1")
       )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, RevoScaleR doesn't support changing the type of a variable in an xdf file (even if you write to a different file). The way to do it is to create a new variable, drop the old, and then rename the new variable to the old name.

I would suggest doing this with a transformFunc (see `?rxTransform` for more information), so that you can create the new variable and drop the old, all in one step:

```
rxDataStep(inXdf, outXdf, transformFunc=function(varlst) {
    varlst$Var1b <- as.numeric(varlst$Var1)
    varlst$Var1 <- NULL
    varlst
}, transformVars="Var1")

# this is fast as it only modifies the xdf metadata, not the data itself
names(outXdf)[names(outXdf) == "Var1b"] <- "Var1"
```

Comment: What's the reason that RevoScaleR doesn't allow to manipulate an existing variable in place?

Comment: I'm not in the engineering team so I can't give a definitive answer, but it would be for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

`MSR` doesn't allow you to overwrite a variable in place with a different variable type.

You have two options: Write to a different variable or write to a different file.  I have added a bit of code that shows that both solutions work as stated in `MRS 9.0.1`. As stated in the comments, there is some point in earlier versions where this might not work.  I am not totally sure where that point is, so the code should let you know.

```
input_xdf <- "test.xdf"
modified_xdf <- "test_out.xdf"

xdf_data <- data.frame(Var1 = as.character(1:10),
                       Var2 = 2:11,
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

rxDataStep(inData = xdf_data,
           outFile = input_xdf,
           rowsPerRead = 5,
           overwrite = TRUE)

rxDataStep(inData = input_xdf, 
           outFile = input_xdf, 
           overwrite = TRUE,
           transforms = list(Var1b = as.numeric(Var1)),
           transformVars = c("Var1")
)

rxGetInfo(input_xdf, getVarInfo = TRUE, numRows = 5)

rxDataStep(inData = input_xdf, 
           outFile = modified_xdf,
           transforms = list(Var1 = as.numeric(Var1)),
           transformVars = c("Var1")
)

rxGetInfo(modified_xdf, getVarInfo = TRUE, numRows = 5)
```

Comment: Actually, your second option won't work (one of those annoying warts in RevoScaleR). I don't think there's any way to change the type of an existing variable, even if you write to a different file.

Comment: @HongOoi, That may have been true before, but is not true now.  I tested before I posted.  Both solutions work.  I'll add some code to make it a working example.

Comment: I'm getting mixed results. Email sent.